# Series vanishes for all powers $k$ implies each term vanishes

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, finite-fields

Suppose we have that for $n$ fixed and $\{a_i\}$ fixed  that 
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^k = 0
$$
for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Under what conditions does this imply that $a_i = 0$ for all $i$? I'd like to know what conditions on the underlying field there are (I'm suspicious that finite characteristic would mess things up) and if this holds for infinite sums.

Comment: Well, some simple cases:   if the field is $\mathbb R$ then just knowing it for a single even $k$ is enough.  If the characteristic $p$ divides $n$ then taking $a_i=1$ for all $i$ is a counterexample.

Comment: In zero characteristic show that the symmetric polynomials in $a_k$ vanish by the usual arguments, so the polynomial with roots $a_k$ is then just $x^n$ etc; in finite characteristic you will have trouble when the characteristic is at most $n$ as for example in the field with two elements $a_1=a_2=1$ and all other $a$'s zero work and this extends to all primes $p \le n$; if $p>n$ the arguments from zero characteristic work as you need only the first $n$ symmetric polynomials to be zero

Comment: Just in case you are unfamiliar, the "usual arguments" that Conrad refers to are [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).